# What is the proper place of favicon references in <head>?

Tags: html, favicon

Should I change something in the following code? Does it make any difference?

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Example Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
  <!--Material Design Icons-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#413b3b">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ff0000">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-144x144.png">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
</head>
```

Comment: What's your concern? As long as those files exist and can be successfully downloaded, it's all good. Are you running into any issues? Please elaborate why you're wondering if you need to change anything in that segment. Unless you're having any issues, it looks fine.

Comment: Everything works as it meant to be. I just wanted to make sure that I used the proper order. I see, it doesn't really matter as long as I don't experience any issues.

Comment: Correct :) This is perfectly fine. There are certain recommendations about where to put `script` and `stylesheet` directives to enhance page performance. It's not something that you need to worry about at the beginning of your development, but if you end up using super large javascript or css files (think larger than 500kb), then it would be worthwhile to be fussy and put those in the right places. But what you have here is just fine, and the order of those smaller files (favicon, manifests, etc.) really do not matter at all.

Comment: I was confused because I read this: (https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#rel-icon) They upload a stylesheet after favicons.

Comment: Interesting! I admire your curiosity and digging through the spec. Just beware of over analyzing the simple stuff though. Keep in mind that browsers will zip through that `head` block in a fraction of a millisecond, parse things out (pretty leniently and intelligently actually, correcting for some mistakes even), take what they need, and render your page in as an optimized manner as possible. Always a great idea to be spec-compliant, but also trust that modern browsers can handle a lot on their own.

Comment: Also, open up the Developers Tool on Chrome, go to the Audit tab, and start an audit of your page. After a few seconds, you'll get a pretty cool report telling you a lot about your page, whether or not there's anything in it that's wrong or could be optimized, etc. It's mostly focused on performance, and is a great tool to make improvements.

Comment: I spent a few hours reading about favicons, and still I'm not 100% sure what the best approach is. Finally, I decided to go with Favicon generator and the  above code. What a helpful tip! I'll go with Audit asap!

Answer (score 1):

You need to put this line before `</head>` tag

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
```

Comment: I thought it's optional if I have favicon.ico in my root. Btw, you can just use 'icon' instead of 'shortcut icon'. "The popular <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"> theoretically identifies two relations, "shortcut" and "icon", but "shortcut" is not registered and is redundant. In 2011 the HTML living standard[16] specified that for historical reasons "shortcut" is allowed immediately before "icon";[17] however, "shortcut" does not have a meaning in this context. "

Comment: Yes you are right. But you may place of favicon references in last portion of <head> tag.

Comment: What does it change? It's like 'just in case' approach? What are the benefits?

Comment: It changes nothing but only the standard structure of code.